# Postgres Container Exits After Starting

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm starting a postgres docker container with:

```sh
docker run --name postgres-test-container -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres:latest -p 5432:5432 -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Running `docker ps` doesn't show anything.

Running `docker ps -a` shows **CREATED** `48 second ago` and **STATUS** `Exited (1) 46 seconds ago`

On running `docker logs postgres-test-container`, I get the below message:

```sh
-- Snipped previous init success messages 

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2020-06-17 00:50:03.582 GMT [48] FATAL:  invalid value for parameter "port": "5432:5432"
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

I'm not able to figure out what's wrong here. How do I solve this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the usage:

```
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Options should proceed the image name:

```sh
docker run --name postgres-test-container -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p 5432:5432 -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
docker run --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  postgres:9.5
```

Comment: I'm using the latest image of postgres. As @Andronicus pointed out, options should precede the image name. Your command might have worked if I was usin an older image.